# Ajuda com instalação do Ionic Framework para desenvolvimento Mobile

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, ionic, instalador

Para instalar o **nodejs** mais rescente, segui o exemplo dado através do site abaixo, na nota do erro abaixo, diz que a versão que estou usando é: **0.13.0-pre**

**https://askubuntu.com/questions/49390/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-node-js**

Segui esse tutorial para instalar o software do Ionic Framework no meu Ubuntu 14.4 LTS:

**http://tutsmais.com.br/blog/ionicframework/o-que-eu-preciso-saber-para-comecar-com-ionic-framework/**

Ao final da tentativa de instalação, estou recebendo a seguinte mensagem de erro, alguém sabe o que estou fazendo de errado:

```
npm ERR! Linux 3.16.0-46-generic
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "cordova" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v0.13.0-pre
npm ERR! npm v2.14.1
npm ERR! code ENOTSUP
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: gulp@3.8.8 
npm ERR! notsup Required: {"node":">= 0.9"}
npm ERR! notsup Actual: {"npm":"2.14.1","node":"0.13.0-pre"}
```

Comment: Coloquei uma outra solução [nesse post](http://eupaulo.com/instalacao-do-ionic-e-nodejs.html). Talvez ajude alguém.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como eu, deve ter outras pessoas que sofreram nisso, então vou deixar a resposta que resolveu meu problema:

1) Baixei o pacote de instalação:

```
wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.7/node-v0.12.7-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

2) Depois acessei o diretório para descompactar o node:

```
cd /usr/local && sudo tar --strip-components 1 -xzf ~/node-v0.12.7-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

3) Aqui verifiquei as versões que estão instaladas:

```
node --version
npm --version
```

4) Depois instalei as bibliotecas essenciais:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev apache2-utils
```

5) E por fim, instalei o Cordova e o Ionic Framework:

```
sudo npm install -g cordova ionic
```

6) Entrei no diretório /var/www/html/apps/ E criei minha aplicação:

```
ionic start testeProject blank
```

E funcionou!!!

> **Editado desse ponto em diante pelo seguinte motivo:**
> Estou acrescentando mais informações úteis.

Após criar a aplicação, dentro do diretório:

```
/var/www/html/apps/testeProject/
```

Executei-a através da linha de comando no terminal `ionic serve`. 
Que carrega a execução assíncrona da sua aplicação, enquanto você edita na sua IDE, ele automaticamente atualiza na tela.

Comment: Ivan. Eu fiz os mesmos processos que você. Mas quando faço esse comando: `ionic emulate ios` não emula. Eu uso Mac OS Yosemite 10.10.5. E tenho o XCode 7 atualizado recentemente. Daí quando rodo esse comando diz que o XCode não pode ser aberto por causa da versão do Sistema Operacional. Tem outro jeito de emular ?

Comment: O erro é esse: **Consulte o desenvolvedor para certificar-se de que Simulator funciona com esta versão do OS X. Talvez você tenha que reinstalar o aplicativo. Certifique-se de instalar todas as atualizações disponíveis do aplicativo e do OS X.**

Comment: Tem problema eu rodar num servidor Mamp (Xampp) ? Muda alguma coisa ? A versão do meu NodeJs é 4.2.2 e do NPM é 2.14.7.

Comment: Esse procedimento é para linux. para OS-X deve ser diferente.

Comment: É comando Linux também.

Comment: Para emular, acredito que você tem que incluir a platform não?

Comment: Um usuário já me ajudou. Obrigado. Eu rodei o `ionic serve --lab`, ficou top.

Comment: para que serve esse --lab?

Comment: É como um emulador, roda ele pra você ver e escolhe a opção `localhost`. Minha aplicação está na pasta Localhost. Provavelmente você terá que escolher a opção que mostra o IP da sua máquina. Ele abre uma página de internet com dois ambientes - iOS e Android. Para ver como está ficando o app.